# Difficulty in sourcing tcl files from sharepoint

Tags: url, sharepoint, tcl

I have tcl byte code on sharepoint with url like
https://share.abc.com/sites/abc/test.tcl
I want to source this file in another tcl file residing on my machine.
I don't want to copy the file from sharepoint.
Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

The `source` command only reads from the filesystem, but that can be a *virtual* filesystem. Thus, you can use the [tclvfs](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2466) package to make it so that HTTP sites can be mounted within the process, and then you can read from that.

```
# Add in HTTPS support
package require http
package require tls
::http::register https 443 ::tls::socket

# Mount the site; the vfs::urltype package won't work as it doesn't support https
package require vfs::http
# Double quotes only because of Stack Overflow highlighting sucking
vfs::http::Mount "https://share.abc.com/" /https.share.abc.com

# Load and evaluate the file
source /https.share.abc.com/sites/abc/test.tcl
```

This all assumes that you don't need any username/password credentials. If you do, you need to set them as part of the mount:

```
vfs::http::Mount "https://theuser:thepassword@share.abc.com/" /https.share.abc.com
```

Note that this currently *requires* that you're using HTTP Basic Auth (over HTTPS). That's sufficiently secure for almost any reasonable use.

---

This is quite a large stack of stuff. You can do it in rather less if you are willing to do some more of the work yourself:

```
package require base64
package require http
package require tls
::http::register https 443 ::tls::socket

proc source_https {url username password} {
    set auth "Basic [base64::encode ${username}:${password}]"
    set headers [list Authorization $auth]
    set tok [http::geturl $url -headers $headers]
    if {[http::ncode $tok] != 200} {
        # Cheap and nasty version...
        set msg [http::code $tok]
        http::cleanup $tok
        error "Problem with fetch: $msg"
    }
    set script [http::data $tok]
    http::cleanup $tok
    # These next two commands are effectively what [source] does (apart from I/O)
    info script $url
    uplevel 1 $script
}

source_https "https://share.abc.com/sites/abc/test.tcl" AzureDiamond hunter2
```

Comment: I don't know whether Sharepoint works with Basic Auth. If not, it's going to involve one of the more [advanced techniques from the Tcler's Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/6087)…